# Displaying selected values only in VB6

Tags: sql, ms-access, datagrid, vb6, ado

I am trying to display students in a datagrid that have "yes" as active. If the student has "no" as active, the form has to hide it and only show the students with "yes".
The problem that I am recieving now is

> Syntax error in FROM clause.

code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim sql As String

connSearch.Open connstr
Adodc1.ConnectionString = conn.connstr

sql = "select * from Table1 where Active  <>" & "'No'"

Adodc1.RecordSource = sql
Set StudentTable.DataSource = Adodc1
Adodc1.Refresh
Adodc1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the table actually named "Table1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `Active`?
If `Active` is `Boolean` data type (Yes/No), it's optional values are `True` or `False`. In that case your query is:

```
"select * from Table1 where Active <> False"
```

If `Active` is `String` data type; are `'no'` and `'No'` the same values? you are better converting all to lower or upper case:

```
"select * from Table1 where Ucase(Active) <> 'NO'"
```

**Edit: Modified Code**

```
Dim sql As String

sql = "select * from Table1 where [Active] <> 'No'"
Adodc1.ConnectionString = conn.connstr
Adodc1.CommandType = adCmdText
Adodc1.RecordSource = sql
Set StudentTable.DataSource = Adodc1
Adodc1.Refresh
Adodc1.Visible = False
```

Comment: I used the second choice and it still gives me **Syntax error in FROM clause.** When i debug it, it shows **false**  in the statement `Adodc1.refresh`.

Comment: Please check if he table name (`Table1`) is spelled correctly.

Comment: And I advise to also make sure `Active` is really of a String type, not `Yes/No`, in other words, that 'No' is actually a `String`

Comment: Yes it is a string type, in the database you can right either "yes" or "no".

Comment: And is the table name spelled correctly? and I also suggest you open the table in design view, and see there the data type of `Active`, typing in spreadsheet view is not always a definite indication...

Comment: The Table name is spelt correctly and the Data type for Active is **Short Text** and the field size is 25.

Comment: see what happens when you copy&paste the SQL to a query object in SQL view. See also if the field name is spelled correctly, and if you have sufficient spaces between the table name, and the `WHERE` saved word.

Comment: **OR**, if the table name contains 2 words. enclose them in square brackets, like this: `[Table Name]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117148/discussion-between-talal-abdoh-and-marlan).

Comment: The Table name is Table1 and i do have sufficient space between the table name `sql = "select * from [Table1] WHERE Active <> 'no'"`

Comment: AFAIK SQL, there is no syntax error in the SQL you have posted above. my last Idea for Access: maybe `Active` is a saved word? try enclosing it in square brackets: `[Active]`. otherwise, it may be some ADO error...

Comment: it is not a reserved word, this is a list of all the reserved words: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286335

Comment: Have you tried the square brackets? if not that I'm sorry, I see know Error in you code. I guess I still have what to learn... maybe  @hansup or somone else would know how to help.

Comment: yes i tried the square brackets. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I need the line **Adodc1.CommandType = adCmdText** for it to work. Thanks again for your help.